# Symfony ESI fragments are not found on production environnement

Tags: symfony, esi

I tried to put Varnish with ESI support like Symfony's documentation suggest.

So, I set my trusted proxies and the fragment path.

Everything works fine in DEV environnement, but in production, I got 404 error Not found for fragments.

It's not a symfony cache problem. I deleted all the cache but i continue getting this 404 error.

It was an apache 404 error response not generated by Symfony, so i tried to add the app.php in the URL and i got the fragment.

```
esi: { enabled: true }
trusted_proxies: [192.168.1.0/24, 10.0.0.0/8, 127.0.0.0/24]
fragments:       { path: /_fragment }
```

So the problem is clear: It's HTACCESS problem. How to fix this ? Why they don't talk about this in Symfony documentation ?

Have you any answer ?

I'm using symfony 2.6.

Thank you.